# Debug Maven plugin under Eclipse 

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven, maven-plugin

I'd like to debug a Maven plugin under Eclipse. I figure I could put it as a dependency; then write some java class that imports the plugin (somehow), and run it as an execution of the maven 'exec' plugin, the 'java' goal? Would this be doable or 'too hard'?

(Btw, use case: it's the hibernate3 plugin I can't get to generate the sql. Can get it to generate xml like 'Level.hbm.xml', though. I'm out of ideas. I might create a question of its own.)

(EDIT: proper headline, added tag.)

-EDIT2-

I see now that I may not have explained exactly what I wanted: I want to debug the plugin as it runs in the project where it is used. I'd like it to find its parameters/configuration from the pom.xml when I start debugging, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) Eclipse plugin, you can do the following:

- Download and open other Maven projects, e.g. the Hibernate plugin (*File > Import > Maven > Materialize Maven Projects from SCM*)
- Run and debug them locally

Please see https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Developing+and+debugging+Maven+plugins for an example.

Comment: I found 'Materialize Maven Projects' and 'Check out Maven Projects from SCM'. I wonder what the difference is?

Comment: And do you know if I can run them in the project where I use the plugin, not in its own project?

Comment: *Check out from SCM* requires that you have access to the project's SCM system (e.g. SVN). *Materialize* works based on the project's POM file and will pull the project from the public Maven repository. Just give *Materialize* a try...

Comment: Have tried; don't understand it :) After seemingly having selected a pom (e.g. ...:hibernate3:2.2), etc, Eclipse wants me to 'Select Maven projects'. None appear. I don't get what it wants more than the pom.xml. I checked the 'use default workspace location'.

Comment: The link is dead.